# How does one prevent Resharper from reformatting Javascript inside Razor pages?

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2017, resharper

Using VS2017, I am editing Javascript inside a .cshtml page and the Resharper engine keeps reformatting the code.

I don't see an obvious way to turn this functionality off while keeping the formatting of Razor syntax on.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718947/is-there-any-way-to-turn-off-resharper-7-auto-formatting)?

Comment: @JohnWu The problem with that approach is that it's an all or nothing thing.  In other words, if I go to Resharper/Options/Environment/Editor/Editor Appearance and turn off that option under Razor, it turns the feature off for the entire Razor page, not just Javascript.

Comment: You can still apply automatic formatting when you want by hitting `ctrl+alt+enter`. Or you can leave automatic formatting on, but [edit the formatting configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Enforcing_Code_Formatting_Rules.html) so that it formats your Javascript the way you want, or not at all.

Comment: Had a few problems with Resharper in the past, and found they all went away once i uninstalled it. Never needed it for anything.